# ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column jdbc error "uninitialized constant" in jruby 9 and rails 5+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jdbc, jruby

I am attempting to install and run jruby 9.1.7.0 and rails 5.0.1 on Windows 10.  Everything seems to be fine on the install, but as soon as I start a server it immediately fails on a JDBC error.

Java version

```
>java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Jruby version

```
>jruby -v
jruby 9.1.7.0 (2.3.1) 2017-01-11 68056ae Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
25.51-b03 on 1.8.0_51-b16 +jit [mswin32-x86_64]
```

There are no other versions of ruby or rails, or jruby installed, and when I do a gem install of rails everything seems fine.

```
>jruby -S gem install rails
Fetching: i18n-0.8.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.8.0
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5-java.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5-java
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.4-java.gem (100%)
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.0.4-java
Fetching: activesupport-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-5.0.1
Fetching: rack-2.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-2.0.1
Fetching: rack-test-0.6.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-test-0.6.3
Fetching: nokogiri-1.7.0.1-java.gem (100%)
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.7.0.1-java
Fetching: loofah-2.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed loofah-2.0.3
Fetching: rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3
Fetching: rails-dom-testing-2.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-dom-testing-2.0.2
Fetching: builder-3.2.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.2.3
Fetching: erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed erubis-2.7.0
Fetching: actionview-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionview-5.0.1
Fetching: actionpack-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionpack-5.0.1
Fetching: activemodel-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activemodel-5.0.1
Fetching: arel-7.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed arel-7.1.4
Fetching: activerecord-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-5.0.1
Fetching: globalid-0.3.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed globalid-0.3.7
Fetching: activejob-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activejob-5.0.1
Fetching: mime-types-data-3.2016.0521.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mime-types-data-3.2016.0521
Fetching: mime-types-3.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mime-types-3.1
Fetching: mail-2.6.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mail-2.6.4
Fetching: actionmailer-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionmailer-5.0.1
Fetching: nio4r-1.2.1-java.gem (100%)
Successfully installed nio4r-1.2.1-java
Fetching: websocket-extensions-0.1.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed websocket-extensions-0.1.2
Fetching: websocket-driver-0.6.5-java.gem (100%)
Successfully installed websocket-driver-0.6.5-java
Fetching: actioncable-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actioncable-5.0.1
Fetching: thor-0.19.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thor-0.19.4
Fetching: method_source-0.8.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed method_source-0.8.2
Fetching: railties-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed railties-5.0.1
Fetching: bundler-1.14.3.gem (100%)
Bundler and RubyGems.org are free for anyone to use, but maintaining them costs more than $25,000 USD every month. Help us cover those costs so that we can keep the gem ecosystem free for everyone: https://ruby.to/support-bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.14.3
Fetching: sprockets-3.7.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sprockets-3.7.1
Fetching: sprockets-rails-3.2.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sprockets-rails-3.2.0
Fetching: rails-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-5.0.1
35 gems installed
```

I then create a new rails project.

```
>rails new test
  create
  create  README.md
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
  create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
  create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
  create  app/models/application_record.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
  create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/assets/javascripts/channels
  create  app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  bin/update
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/secrets.yml
  create  config/cable.yml
  create  config/puma.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
  create  config/initializers/assets.rb
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
  create  config/initializers/cors.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
  create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/fixtures/files
  create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp
  create  tmp/.keep
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
  remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
     run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies.......
Installing rake 12.0.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.4 (java)
Using i18n 0.8.0
Installing minitest 5.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5 (java)
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using nokogiri 1.7.0.1 (java)
Using rack 2.0.1
Using nio4r 1.2.1 (java)
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 7.1.4
Installing jdbc-sqlite3 3.8.11.2
Using bundler 1.14.3
Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Installing execjs 2.7.0
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using thor 0.19.4
Installing multi_json 1.12.1
Installing puma 3.7.0 (java)
Installing sass 3.4.23
Installing tilt 2.0.6
Installing therubyrhino_jar 1.7.6
Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5 (java)
Using mime-types 3.1
Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
Installing uglifier 3.0.4
Installing therubyrhino 2.0.4
Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
Using activesupport 5.0.1
Installing tzinfo-data 1.2016.10
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.2
Using globalid 0.3.7
Using activemodel 5.0.1
Installing jbuilder 2.6.1
Using actionview 5.0.1
Using activejob 5.0.1
Using activerecord 5.0.1
Using actionpack 5.0.1
Installing activerecord-jdbc-adapter 1.3.22
Using actioncable 5.0.1
Using actionmailer 5.0.1
Using railties 5.0.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Installing activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter 1.3.22
Installing coffee-rails 4.2.1
Installing jquery-rails 4.2.2
Using rails 5.0.1
Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
Bundle complete! 11 Gemfile dependencies, 57 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

At this point I move into the newly created directory and test the app to see if it will start, and it always fails with the same JDBC error.  I have tried specifying mysql and also using the default sqlite, but in both cases I get this:

```
>cd test
>rails server
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from require at bin/rails:4)
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'.
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant     ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::Format
Backtrace for gem load error is:
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:13:in `<module:TypeCast>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:7:in `<module:Jdbc>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:4:in `<module:ConnectionAdapters>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:3:in `<main>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:1:in `singleton class'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:70:in `<class:singleton class>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:68:in `<module:JdbcColumn>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:12:in `<module:ConnectionAdapters>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:2:in `<main>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/column.rb:1:in `<main>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:1:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:1:in `<module:(root)>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:9:in `<main>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:1:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:1:in `<main>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:52:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:52:in `<main>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:3:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:3:in `block in (root)'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc.rb:1:in `each'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc.rb:1:in `block in (root)'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc.rb:9:in `each'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc.rb:9:in `(root)'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter-1.3.22/lib/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter.rb:1:in `(root)'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter-1.3.22/lib/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter.rb:2:in `<main>'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:1:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:1:in `block in (root)'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `tap'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:

  block in require at C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-    1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:95
          each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1733
  block in require at C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-    1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86
          each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1733
       require at C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75
       require at C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler.rb:107
        <main> at C:/Users/Adam/JrubyProjects/musicq/config/application.rb:7
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961
   block in (root) at C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:1
           tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1747
        server at C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88
        server at C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85
        <main> at C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961
        <main> at bin/rails:4
```

If I specify "rails new test -d mysql" I will get the same error but from the "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter".

When I switched to "jruby 1.7.26" and installed "rails 3.1.3" everything works perfectly - I create the app, the server starts without error and I can view the default welcome page that rails creates.

I've looked extensively for anything related to jruby 9, rails and windows 10 to see if this is a known issue, but I haven't been able to find anything.  Has anyone else encountered this problem?  Does anyone know of a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I can now add "also on Debian Linux" to this error.  I have now tried doing the exact same thing and gotten the same error.  The Linux install is using RVM with jruby-9.1.6.0 and rails 5.0.1 and it causes the exact same error.

Comment: I have found this issue on GitHub: 
https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/703
https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/700
https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/704
https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/705
...facepalm.

Comment: Apparently I'm the only person to ask specifically about "ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::Format", but there's a bunch of chat about "ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES" and "ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::FALSE_VALUES", which are all basically the same error to do with missing constants.  :-/

Comment: I'm going to leave this unanswered because the only solution I've found is to rollback the rails gem to version 4.2.7.1 when using jruby.